# country flag and country code not showing in django form and admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-phone-field

I'm using `django-phonenumber_field` in my model, but when added a `PhoneNumberField` in my model, and add it to my `forms.py` file it does not show a country flag with their country code like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcalderaforms.com%2Fdoc%2Fphone-number-better%2F&psig=AOvVaw0gtznd3AQZpZIgzkXlbhDd&ust=1681038851294000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBEQjRxqFwoTCIjMsO-Tmv4CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAK) in template, how can i solve this problem?

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$')])
```

```
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'category', 'description', 'phone_number']
```

settings.py:

```
PHONENUMBER_DB_FORMAT = 'INTERNATIONAL'
PHONENUMBER_DB_FORMAT="RFC3966"
```